# activecollab 5 nginx url rewrite not working

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, activecollab

I was trying to install Activecollab as per the [instructions here](https://activecollab.com/help/books/self-hosted/installation).

My vhost config for nginx is [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e66e5094ddff71e8ea9e144647662358)

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name collab.example.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/ac.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/ac.error.log;

    set $root_path /usr/share/nginx/html/collabs/public;
    root $root_path;

    index index.html index.htm index.php router.php;
    charset utf-8;

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/assets/(.*)$ /assets/$1 last;
        rewrite ^/avatars/(.*)$ /avatars/$1 last;
        rewrite ^/wallpapers/(.*)$ /wallpapers/$1 last;
        rewrite ^/verify-existence$ /verify.php last;
        rewrite ^/proxy.php$ /proxy.php last;
        rewrite ^/api/v([0-9]*)/(.*)$ /api.php?path_info=$2&api_version=$1 last;
        rewrite ^$ /router.php last;
        rewrite ^(.*) /router.php?path_info=$1 last;
    }


    location ~ ^/(assets|avatars|wallpapers)/ {
        root $root_path;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 150;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

Output of `nginx -V`

`nginx version: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-threads`

I am getting error

> Error — URL rewriting is not enabled. Invalid URL rewrite check response:

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you run `nginx -t`?

Comment: @TarunLalwani its working, I am able to see my other websites. `nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok`

Comment: where exactly are you getting the error you have specified? Also please add `nginx -V` output to your question

Comment: @TarunLalwani see my edit.

Comment: you didn't update about where you are seeing this error? Can you please elaborate that?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I am seeing it on the front end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157640/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-niksmac).

Comment: Where are you getting the error: "Error — URL rewriting is not enabled. Invalid URL rewrite check response:" from?

Comment: @niksmac, any update on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed over chat and teamviewer debug session. There is a flag `REDIRECT_CHECK` in `config.php` for activecollab. You need to disable this redirection by defining this name in config

```
define('REDIRECT_CHECK',false);
```

Also you should change below part of nginx config from

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^/assets/(.*)$ /assets/$1 last;
    rewrite ^/avatars/(.*)$ /avatars/$1 last;
    rewrite ^/wallpapers/(.*)$ /wallpapers/$1 last;
    rewrite ^/verify-existence$ /verify.php last;
    rewrite ^/proxy.php$ /proxy.php last;
    rewrite ^/api/v([0-9]*)/(.*)$ /api.php?path_info=$2&api_version=$1 last;
    rewrite ^$ /router.php last;
    rewrite ^(.*) /router.php?path_info=$1 last;
}
```

to

```
location / { 
  if (!-e $request_filename) { 
     rewrite ^/assets/(.*)$ /assets/$1 last; 
     rewrite ^/avatars/(.*)$ /avatars/$1 last; 
     rewrite ^/wallpapers/(.*)$ /wallpapers/$1 last; 
     rewrite ^/verify-existence$ /verify.php last; 
     rewrite ^/proxy.php$ /proxy.php last; 
     rewrite ^/api/v([0-9]*)/(.*)$ /api.php?path_info=$2&api_version=$1 last; 
     rewrite ^$ /router.php last; 
     rewrite ^(.*) /router.php?path_info=$1 last; 
   } 
   try_files $uri $uri/ /router.php?path_info=$uri&$args; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With the help of [Tarun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2830850/tarun-lalwani) I managed to resolve this. What we did is

1. Confirmed that this has nothing to do with nginx and rules
2. Disabled the REDIRECT_CHECK in configuration files.

Now it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Added a detailed answer with our findings

Comment: @TarunLalwani up voted and bounty issued, btc shall follow.

Comment: @TarunLalwani are you rich now? :D

Comment: The BTC never followed, but those who learn and share always are rich :-)

Comment: @TarunLalwani long time :D